# DefaultTableModel setValueAt throwing ArrayIndexOutOfboundsException

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My requirement is  to show StockQuote Symbols (Streaming Data ) in a Grid .
For this I have chosen `JTable`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Preethi {

    protected void initUI() {
        final Random random = new Random();

        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "Id", "Name", "Desg", "Sal" }, 0);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Preethi.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Random ran = new Random(12);
        ran.nextFloat();

        String str = new String("sss");

        String[] socrates = {str, str, str };
        model.addRow(socrates);

        System.out.println(model.getRowCount());
        System.out.println(model.getColumnCount());

        model.setValueAt(new Object[]{"ewqeq","rtgre","gfdgd","mbmnb"}, 1, 4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Preethi().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: First mistake: your Employee class has static variables and static getters, but instance setters. That makes no sense. Get rid of the static throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the value of a row that doesn't exist.

`DefaultTableModel` has a [`addRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

As mentioned by Jon, you shouldn't be using static methods and fields for your data objects

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282753/firetablerowsupdated-not-work-after-update-done-in-jtable

Answer (score 1):

```
model.setValueAt(new Object[]{"ewqeq","rtgre","gfdgd","mbmnb"}, 1, 4);
```

Row one does not exist so you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.` So as suggested by MadProgrammer use [addRow(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method and pass your object to that.

**Example:**

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{"ewqeq","rtgre","gfdgd","mbmnb"});
```

**UPDATE:**

You have defined only 4 columns so index will be from 0 to 3. But you have given 4 in `setValueAt` method. So you the problem remains same. Change it to 3.

Comment: Thanks Che , i used the same setValueAt with 1 , 4 . (in  my program ),but still the same

Comment: _SetValueAt_ will update the existing one. So if that row exists then you can update else you will not be able to. Whereas _addRow_ will add a new row to the existing rows.