# fireTableRowsUpdated() Not work after update done in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my JTable, after update done, it need to refresh to show the changes:

```
public class RecordTableGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private String newName;
private JTable table;
private RecordTableModel myModel;
private JButton editButton;

    public RecordTableGUI() {
    myModel = new RecordTableModel();
    table = new JTable(myModel);

    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonsPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 550);
    setLocation(300, 80);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel buttonsPanel() {
    JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
    editButton = new JButton("Edit");
    editButton.addActionListener(this);
    bPanel.add(editButton);
    return bPanel;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
        Object oldName = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1);

        UpdateGUIDialog updDialog = new UpdateGUIDialog(this,String.valueOf(oldName), this);

        int rowToEdit = table.getSelectedRow();
        int rowToModel = table.convertRowIndexToView(rowToEdit);
        Object nameID = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        myModel.updateRow(rowToModel, nameID, getNewName());
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a row");
    }
}
}
```

Model Class:

```
public class RecordTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
Connection con;
Statement statement;
ResultSet result;
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
String query = "Select * from mytable";
ArrayList<String> cols = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    public RecordTableModel() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
        statement = con.createStatement();
        result = statement.executeQuery(query);

        int c = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            cols.add(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
        }

        while (result.next()) {

            ArrayList<String> eachRow = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
                eachRow.add(result.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(eachRow);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlee) {
            sqlee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    @Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return cols.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    ArrayList<String> selectedRow = data.get(rowIndex);
    return selectedRow.get(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return cols.get(col);
}
    public void updateRow(int modelRow, Object nameID, Object newName) {
        String query = "update mytable set name = '" + newName + "' where id = " + nameID;
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement pstate;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
        pstate = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstate.executeUpdate();
        fireTableRowsUpdated(tableRow, tableRow);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        fireTableCellUpdated(modelRow, 1);
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        sql.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've been asked several times before -- show us an [sscce](http://sscce.org), and you continue to ignore our requests. How are we to know why your code isn't working based on these crap snippets? Why bother helping you if you don't contribute as well?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that solution does not work in here!

Comment: `that solution does not work in here!` -- what solution? Using an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to show us what you're doing wrong is not going to "work"? Hate to say it but what you're posting isn't going to work as well. If we can't understand your problem, you will not get knowledgeable help. It's up to you -- how much need is there for you to solve this problem? If it's great, then put in the requisite effort. If not, then no biggie.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my code is so little, what is it's deficiency?

Comment: Posting a SSCCE will almost always work. In your case you need to post a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem without using a database because we don't have access to your database.

Comment: The deficiency is in **code not shown**. Period.

Comment: @camickr i remove database related codes

Comment: Where are you updating the data held by the table model? You just run a database query, but where do you get the result set? Where do you insert the result set into the data of the model? You need to show the problem in a way we can understand it.

Comment: Did you even read the link on what a SSCCE is??? How does that code compile? Why are you even using a custom model? In the past you have been told that the DefaultTableModel will do what you need. You where given a link that showed how to add data to the model from a database. The model also supports an addRow() method.

Comment: @camickr: he's been given links to the specification in several of his recent questions here. If he hasn't read it yet, then shame on him.

Comment: @camickr i am using `AbstractTableModel` in my class. I add two Classes

Comment: @Sajjad, Do you know what the word compile means? Does the code you posted in the forum compile? The code you posted makes absolutely no sense to me. I have no idea what the "Edit" button does. Where is your GUI that shows a table along with the EDIT button. What part of SSCCE do you not understand???

Comment: @camickr, I add compilable code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I do all of that in `RecordTableModel` constructor

Comment: I already mentioned that SQL code should not be included because we don't have access to your database. Your question is about displaying data it the JTable, not about how to update data in a database. No where in your code to you udate the data in the TableModel. When you loaded the data from the database you added it to the "data" variable. When you update/change the data you also need to update the "data" variable. Why are you using a custom model? The DefaultTableModel will update the model for you. Then you add code to update the database.

Comment: @camickr, When should use `custom model` and when should use `DefaultTableModel ` ?

Comment: First you need to understand your requirement. The DefaultTableModel allows dynamic updates to the model. You have a requirement that you also need to update the database when the data changes. So is it easier to extend the DefaultTableModel to update the database or is it easier to create a completely new model? Based on the code provided you could extend the DefaultTableModel and add an updateRow(...) method. You could then invoke setValueAt(...) to update each column in the row. Then you invoke your code to update the database.

Comment: @camickr Well, So in my purpose `DefaultTableModel` is better and easier. One note, Should i override `DefaultTableModel` methods? I know that for remove and update and add row functions, I should defined this methods on model Class. Should i override ` setValueAt(...) ` method of this Class or not?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your original code:

```
public class RecordTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
...
    public void updateRow(int modelRow,...) {
    String query = ...;
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement pstate;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        pstate = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstate.executeUpdate();
        fireTableRowsUpdated(modelRow, modelRow);     // Not Work!
        fireTableDataChanged();                       // Not Work!
        fireTableCellUpdated(modelRow, 1);           // Not Work!
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        sql.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code does nothing to the data held by the table model itself, and so it should come as no surprise that calling `fireTableXXX(...)` does nothing. If the model is  unchanged, you can fire anything you want, and the table won't change.

You should perhaps not be using executeUpdate but executeQuery so you can get a ResultSet from the database, and then use it to update the data held by your table model. **Then** call your appropriate `fireTableXXX(...)` method.